# How to find index value from meshgrid in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, intersection

I have the following problem: I have two surface equations, and I am looking at what point they are zero. So I have the following:

```
b = np.arange(0,2,0.1)
k = np.arange(0,50,1)
b,k = np.meshgrid(b,k)
```

with these I produce `z1` and `z2`, massive formulas, but they both use `b` and `k`:

```
z1 = ((0.5*rho*k**2 * Vd**2 * c)*(Cl * 0.1516*b**3 + 
      Cd*(((b*np.sqrt(b**2 * k**2 +1))/(2*k**2)) - 
      ((np.log(np.sqrt(b**2 * k**2 + 1) + b*k))/(2*k**3)))) - F)

z2 = ((Cl * 0.1516 * b**3 * k**(-1)) -
      ((Cd/(8*k**4))*((3*np.log(np.sqrt(b**2 * k**2 + 1) + b*k)) +
      (b*np.sqrt(b**2 * k**2 +1)*(2*b**2 * k**2 -3)*k))))
```

Now I know how to find the closest point at which z1 and z2 are zero. Just like below:

```
print min(z1[(-0.1<z1)&(z1<0.1)]), min(z2[(-0.1<z2)&(z2<0.1)])
```

but with these I only get the z-value which gives me a close value to zero. What I need is to find which `b` and `k` values correspond to that given result of either `z1` or `z2`.

I tried to index it, but I seem not to do it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, your "is close to zero" expression `(-0.1<z1)&(z1<0.1)` is an array of booleans.  To find the indices of the `True` items you simply need to use [`nonzero()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html).

```
(-0.1<z1) & (z1<0.1).nonzero()
```

For example:

```
>>> np.array([False, False, True, False, True, True, False]).nonzero()
(array([2, 4, 5]),)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using argmin on the absolute value of z1 and z2?

Example for how to use argmin:

```
>>> t = np.random.rand(4,3)
>>> t

array([[ 0.55809884,  0.34630428,  0.78713403],
       [ 0.15125035,  0.07231524,  0.06975387],
       [ 0.63233302,  0.48026985,  0.21420412],
       [ 0.32713745,  0.95168682,  0.34994332]])

>>> np.min(t)

0.069753866909461171

>>> np.argmin(t)

5

>>> t[5//3, 5%3] # 5 is the argmin, 3 is my number of columns

0.069753866909461171
```

Comment: A more general method would be to use [`np.unravel_index`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html), e.g. `np.unravel_index(np.argmin(t), t.shape)`

Comment: Well, the thing is, here you only use one parameter "t". What about multiple parameters?

Comment: what do you mean? the last line shows you how to go from the unraveled parameter to the 2 'coordinates' in your array. And ali_m pointed out how to directly get those 2 coordinates - or any of them if you work in a N-dimensional array - which I was not aware of, thanks ali_m!